# Is there a Schengen equivalent of a Redress Control Number?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, schengen, passports, europe, italian-citizens

I recently learnt that I have the same first name, last name and birthdate as someone who has been banned from entering the Schengen area.

According to a border police officer, this will cause me to be sent to secondary screening at passport control basically any single time I cross the Schengen border. It has already happened twice (that's how I learnt about the unfortunate coincidence) and both times it resolved with a short wait until the misunderstanding was cleared up and I was let go. It happened at Amsterdam airport.

I am worried that at other points of entry the treatment might be less amicable and/or the waits will be longer. This would be particularly unfortunate if I have a connecting flight which I might miss if detained at passport control. ([Related question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/181708/maximising-chance-of-making-tight-connection-after-learning-i-will-be-selected-f))

I would like to solve the problem once and for all. I understand that in the U.S. there is a "Redress Control Number" for situations like this. For as much as I am searching the web, I cannot find anything similar for the Schengen area.

Is there anything I can do to, perhaps, match my passport with my real identity? Something that will clearly signal to the immigration authorities that I am myself and not my evil doppelganger? Ideally this would let me pass immigration without going into secondary screening or even using the automated machines.

For reference, my nationality is Italian and my country of residence is Spain. I have a biometric passport issued by Italy.

Comment: You should contact your responsible Italian consulate in Spain so they can determine what type of **alert** this actually is and if it can be adapted to exclude known EU-Citizens.

Comment: And you should also exercise your right to access your personal data in SIS to have an official confirmation you aren't in it, this may help you in further entries. This is done through the [Policia Nacional](https://www.policia.es/_es/tupolicia_conocenos_estructura_cooperacioninternacional.php#) since you reside in Spain

Comment: @MarkJohnson: I will do that. The track record of efficiency of my local Italian consulate is, to use a euphemism, less than stellar. It might take a while before I can update this question with the answer (if at all).

Comment: @NicolasFormichella: great suggestion. I just sent the request on-line. I will update once I have a response.

Comment: Most SIS alerts aren't applicable to EU citizens. That's certainly the case for an alert for refusal of entry and stay. Enquiring doesn't hurt but it's unlikely there is any confusion or that anything can be done about the type of alert. The thing is that if the name and date of birth match that of an alert, border guards are bound to wonder whether the passport is genuine. There isn't really much else to check regarding an Italian citizen.

Comment: @Relaxed: could a rule/exception be recorded, which says "If the person's first name is X and last name is Y and birthdate is Z, **but** their passport number is W, then it's fine", or "**but** they know this secret code, then it's fine", like a US redress code?

Comment: @AlbertoSantini Not that I know of.